# jar file of fxgl project can not find texture

Tags: javafx, jar, textures

i have created a .jar file from a school fxgl project, it is a small game with textures. But as soon as i run the .jar file with the CMD it fails to find the textures

Intellij finds the textures just fine and the game runs as it should. but when when using the .jar file, the texture cant be found.
 I have opened the .jar file with 7-zip and the texures are there, but I assume the assetLoader can't find the texture files when run as jar

i expect the picture to be shown in the top left corner

but i get this message

Message:  Failed to load asset: map of inner saisjo.jpg. Cause: Asset "/assets/textures/map of inner saisjo.jpg" was not found!

Type:  IllegalArgumentException

Method:  AssetLoader.loadFailed()

Line:  AssetLoader.kt:737

Comment: Just guessing from the limited info, but try creating a folder in the same folder as the `Jar`. Name it `assets`. Then create the `textures` subfolder inside it. now add your .jpg files. You need to post your file structure and how you load the images. To get a more specific answer.

Comment: the project structure is src/main/java then my main class and packages with other classes
in src/main/resources/assets/texures are the textures

Intellij outputs artifacts in out/artifacts/gameproject_jar/gameproject.jar
I have put the copied the resources folder in to the same folder as the jar, 
same message